# QtCreator debugger only shows assembler

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, qt-creator

I am using linux, and I am using QTCreator. For some reason, when I run a program in debug mode, when it faults, I get an assembler dump. There is no stack trace or anything Legibile. I think my debugger used to show me this stuff, but somehow has gotten switched off. What can I do to get it back?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that my make and qmake commands were swapped, so the make file was getting built with -O3 instead of -g, even when the program was compiled in debug mode from Qt.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile it with the debug symbols, make the Debug configuration the active one, recompile and run. Or supply the -ggdb gcc switch yourself